# Fixed div cannot scroll when select2 dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

I have select2 in my scrollable fixed div popup like modal. When select2 dropdown, I cannot scroll the div until I close the dropdown first.

It makes the smartphone keyboard blocking out the select, and I cannot scroll it. how to make that fixed div still scrollable when the select2 dropdown.

Here's my fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/rezaiskandar/d8cu9ywf/34/

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="fixed">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content">
      <select class="selectt" name="hehe">
        <option value="" selected>choice 1</option>
        <option value="">choice 2</option>
        <option value="">choice 3</option>                                 </select>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: could you please make a fiddle?

Comment: Please see this post on how to [create-minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: here's my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rezaiskandar/d8cu9ywf/34/

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are fixing the container using `position: fixed` 
If you share your desired design then I will get an idea of what is the actual requirement.

Comment: that is my question, is there a way to make fixed still scrollable when select2 dropdown